# Excel how to look for value in table and return value from another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have an issue in excel where I cannot get it to return a specific value.

I have a table of data like this

```
Week     N1 N2  N3
w0  6   15  24
w1  5   8   9
w2  3   8   17
w3  20  23  31
w4  13  21  23
w5  6   12  15
w6  2   5   20
w7  10  20  21
```

the numbers in N1 N2 and N3 can change and are random.

What I need to be able to do is to lookup any number in the table and return the value in the weeks column.

so for example if I was looking for the number 20 it would return w6.

Ive tried various vlookups, Hlookups, Index and Match variations but just dont seem to be able to get this fairly simple thing to work.

Can anybody help me please, before I explode.

Comment: Why would it return `w6`? `20` appears several times in your table. How did you determine that it would choose `w6` (and not `w3` or `w7`)?

Comment: apologies yes, i want it to return the first instance that 20 appears, so in this example would be w3.

Comment: Please accept one of these answers as correct by placing a checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
= INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(1,MMULT(($B$2:$D$9=20)+0,{1;1;1}),0))
```

**EDIT** *A slightly better formula:*

```
= INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(TRUE,MMULT(($B$2:$D$9=20)+0,{1;1;1})>0,0))
```

It returns the first `Week` where a match is found in the table.

Obviously just replace `20` above with whatever value you want to look up.

See example below.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

More generally, instead of hardcoding `{1;1;1}` into the formula, you can make this dynamic, e.g.

```
= INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(1,MMULT(($B$2:$D$9=20)+0,TRANSPOSE((COLUMN($B$1:$D$1)>0)+0)),0))
```

Also, if you want to search the table from left to right instead of top to bottom, do this:

```
= INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(1,MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW($A$2:$A$9)>0)+0),($B$2:$D$9=20)+0),0))
```

Note, both of these are now array formulas (must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Another method,

```
=index(A:A, iferror(match(G5, B:B, 0), iferror(match(G5, C:C, 0), match(G5, D:D, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Technically, this returns the first match that is found from left to right, instead of top to bottom. Although, I'm not sure who's correct, since the OP doesn't specify whether to search top to bottom or left to right.

Comment: true but there are only 3 columns but 8 rows and my ctrl+v gets tired.

Comment: hi, the first answer provided does exactly what I need.  thank you both for your replies